# exceeded the 'max_user_connections' resource

Tags: c#, mysql, conexão

Não sei bem qual o motivo do erro que estou tendo mas parece que é algo referente as conexões abertas no banco, onde está ocorrendo erro caso a aplicação tente criar mais conexões que o limite. Creio que este seja o motivo do erro.

Estou fechando toda Conexão que abro para um interação (insert/update/delete/select).

Já li alguns tópicos sobre isso aqui no Stack Overflow, mas nenhum baseado em C# que tenha resolvido esse problema.

Segue código de conexão ao meu `db` e uma interação como exemplo:

Classe para Conexão:

```
 public class ClassConexao  
    {
     public static MySqlConnection ObterConexao()
     {           
       MySqlConnection conectar = new MySqlConnection("server=ENDEREÇO; database=NOME; Uid=USER; pwd=****");

       conectar.Open();
       return conectar;           
     }  
}
```

Interação :

```
        try
        {   //ABRINDO CONEXAO01
            MySqlConnection conexão01= ClassConexao.ObterConexao();

            MySqlCommand _comandoSel = new MySqlCommand(String.Format("SELECT Column1, Column2 FROM tableA WHERE Column1 = " + "500" + ""), conexão01);
            MySqlDataReader 01_reader = _comando01.ExecuteReader();
            Sel_reader.Read();

            textbox1.Text = 01_reader.GetString(0);
            textbox2.Text = 01_reader.GetString(1);

            //FECHANDO CONEXAO01
            conexão01.Close();

        catch (Exception error)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(String.Format("Algo está errado com a operação! {0}", error.Message));
            return;
        }
```

Mensagem de erro retornada:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Existe alguma forma de aumentar esse limite? Ou outra solução que não limite as conexões?

Comment: Da um Dispose na conexão depois do Close e ve se resolve.

Comment: @Ricardo Como eu uso o Dispose ? conexao01.Dispose(); ?

Comment: Olha a minha resposta, acredito que isso possa resolver.

Answer (score 3):

Assumindo que você você está usando o [MySqlConnection](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-ref-mysqlclient-mysqlconnectionmembers.html) então você dever conseguir fazer assim:

```
try
   {   //ABRINDO CONEXAO01
       MySqlConnection conexão01= ClassConexao.ObterConexao();

       MySqlCommand _comandoSel = new MySqlCommand(String.Format("SELECT Column1, Column2 FROM tableA WHERE Column1 = " + "500" + ""), conexão01);
       MySqlDataReader 01_reader = _comando01.ExecuteReader();
       Sel_reader.Read();

       textbox1.Text = 01_reader.GetString(0);
       textbox2.Text = 01_reader.GetString(1);

       //FECHANDO CONEXAO01
       conexão01.Close();

       catch (Exception error)
       {
          MessageBox.Show(String.Format("Algo está errado com a operação! {0}", error.Message));
          return;
       }
        finally
       {
           conexão01.Dispose(); // << AQUI VOCÊ LIBERA TODOS OS RECURSOS USADOS
        }
```

Assim fica mais correto, faz as verificações devidas em cada lugar no seu sistema que for utilizar.

Comment: Se estourar uma exception no meio caminho os recursos não vão ser liberados...

Comment: Atualizei o código! Vlw! Também coloquei para ele observar cada lugar que for implementar isso. Obrigado.

Comment: Boa. Agora sim, +1

Comment: @Ricardo Não ajudou muito cara, coloquei o `Dispose()` após todos meus `Close()`. mas ainda não consigo ter mais que 4 ou 5 pessoas trabalhando no sistema.

Comment: Maurício, talvez você realmente tenha muita gente usando o sistema, o que você pode tentar é melhorar seu métodos onde o banco é usado, tipo, abre o banco, faz o necessário de uma vez só e fecha, depois faz o resto. As vezes tem uma rotina que abre a conexão com o banco e manda uma mensagem no meio do caminho, ou faz muita coisa antes de fechar. É o máximo que consigo ajudar sem ver o código todo.

Answer (score 1):

Se deseja expandir o limite de conexões, como menciona, o limite deve ser expandido diretamente no [`my.cnf`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/option-files.html), se você tiver acesso a este arquivo.

Na verdade existem dois parâmetros para serem alterados:

- `max_connections` estabelece o máximo de conexões que podem existem simultaneamente.
- `max_user_connections` estabelece o máximo de conexões simultâneas que podem existir por cada usuário, isso é o número máximo de conexão por cada `USER` do MySQL.

Se você tiver acesso ao `my.cnf` basta que altere os parâmetros como desejar, esteja atento que o uso de CPU e principalmente RAM vão aumentar conforme a maior quantidade de requisições simultâneas, *ou seja por mais que possa definir "99999999" haverá limites de hardware.*

Verifique dando um `SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST` no MySQL para ver as conexões que estão abertas e o que está sendo feito.

---

Além disso, para não ter que reiniciar o MySQL para que os novos parametros sejam utilizados, modifique utilizando o `SET GLOBAL`.

```
SET GLOBAL max_user_connections = 500;
SET GLOBAL max_connections = 500;
```

Para que isto funcione o usuário do MySQL, *que irá executar esta query*, precisa do privilégio global. Essa mudança não é permanente, sempre que o MySQL desligar irá retornar ao valor definido no `my.cnf`, portanto alterar o `my.cnf` é necessário.

Comment: Eu tentei coloca o `Dispose()` como o Ricardo disse na outra resposta, mas ainda não aliviou o sistema. acho que aumentar esse limite como você disse seria a solução, mas eu acho que não tenho acesso a esse my.cnf aí não.. 

tem como aumentar o limite de alguma outra forma ? 

do jeito que estou 4 ou 5 usuários logados ao mesmo tempo. ja excede 30 User_Connections que é onde da o erro !

Comment: Depende do servidor, isso não está na pergunta. Se estiver em servidor compartilhado é impossível, essa limitação geralmente está nos termos e é "imutável". Se estiver um VPS/Dedicado você pode mudar. Se estiver usando algum banco de dados oferecido como serviço (como Google Cloud SQL, Rackspace Cloud Database...), cada tipo é um tipo, pode ser que cada plano pode ter um limite ou pode ser ajustado nas opções, inclusive podem permitir alterar o my.cnf. Enfim depende de onde está o MySQL.